# Series Summation to calculate algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory

I have an algorithm, and I need to calculate its complexity. I'm close to the answer but I have a little math problem: what is the summation formula of the series

½(n<sup>4</sup>+n<sup>3</sup>) where the pattern of n is 1, 2, 4, 8, ... so the series becomes:

½(1<sup>4</sup>+1<sup>3</sup>) + ½(2<sup>4</sup>+2<sup>3</sup>) + ½(4<sup>4</sup>+4<sup>3</sup>) + ½(8<sup>4</sup>+8<sup>3</sup>) + ...

Comment: It looks like the complexity is O(n^4).

Comment: yes.. but I need the exact formula

Comment: I think you have it.  There may not be a closed-form solution.  You might be better off asking on a math site rather than a programming site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming. It is a math problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might help to express n as 2^k for k=0,1,2...

Substitute that into your original formula to get terms of the form (16^k + 8^k)/2.

You can break this up into two separate sums (one with base 16 and one with base 8), 
each of which is a geometric series.

S1 = 1/2(16^0 + 16^1 + 16^2 + ...)

S2 = 1/2(8^0 + 8^1 + 8^2 + ...)

The J-th partial sum of a geometric series is a(1-r^J)/(1-r)  where a is the initial
value and r the ratio between successive terms.  For S1, a=1/2, r=16.  For S2, a=1/2,
r=8.

Multiply it out and I believe you will find that the sum of the first J terms is O(16^J).

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about

½ Ʃ ((2<sup>r</sup>)<sup>4</sup>+(2<sup>r</sup>)<sup>3</sup>) from r=1 to n

(Sorry for the ugly math; there's no LaTeX here.)

The result is 16/15 16<sup>n</sup> + 8/7 8<sup>n</sup> - 232/105

See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%282%5Er%29%5E4%2B%282%5Er%29%5E3+from+r%3D1+to+n .

You don't need the exact formula. All you need to know is that this is an O(16<sup>n</sup>) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all of u.. the final formula which I was looking for (based on your works) was :

```
((1/15 2^(4(log2(n)+1))  +  8^(log2(n)+1)/7  -232/105)/2) + 1
```

this will gives the same result as the program which runs the algorithm

Answer (score -1):

looks like your series does not converge ... that is, the summation is infinity. maybe your formula is wrong or you asked the question wrong.

Comment: Theta notation for `f(n)` ("big O") doesn't require the series to converge. It just requires the ratio of `f(n)` to `g(n)` to converge, where `g(n)` is some arbitrary function of `n`.

Comment: I suppose I don't understand his notation or technique. The sum of the series he listed is infinity.

Comment: Yes, that series goes to infinity - but the idea is to quantify *how fast* it goes to infinity. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation or http://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

Comment: I know what big O is, as well a little o and theta notation. I have not seen "series summation" used to calculate it. I'll look it up in my copy of the CLRS book to refresh when I get a chance. :)

Comment: If you have CLRS 3E, you want Appendix A (p. 1145.)